# MVC Action isn't triggered in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I made a model, some fields and a button in the view:

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<EnrollSys.Employee>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.name)
    }
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 20%" />
```

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = selectModels();
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<EnrollSys.Employee> model)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

The problem is:

Why the "Save" action isn't fired?

Comment: Firstly you don't have a form - `@using (Html.BeginForm("Save")`. But adding just that means `model` will be null because your not creating your controls correctly - you need a `for` loop, not a `foreach` (the model must be `IList<Employee>`

Comment: You just deleted your other question as I was writing a comment. My best guess is that textbox is in a modal which is loaded after the page is first rendered. If that is the case, then your jquery selector may not work (you might need event delegation)

Comment: @StephenMuecke My new approach will be making a partial view inside the modal and when the user clicks the upload button, the DIV inside the partial view will reload, this might help to solve the binding issue with the help of strongly type partial view

Comment: You are currently binding correctly (the `name` attribute matches the name of the parameter value - its just that its awful code for generating a view). The issue is your code for setting the value via jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `<form>` element to post back your controls. In your case you need to specify the action name because its not the same as the method thet generated the view (`Index()`)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save"))
{
   .... // your controls and submit button
}
```

This will now post back to your `Save()` method, however the model will be null because your `foreach` loop is generating duplicate `name` attributes without indexers meaning that they cannot be bound to a collection (its also creating invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes).

You need to use a `for` loop (the model must implement `IList`) or a custom `EditorTemplate` for type of `Employee`.

**Using a for loop**

```
@model IList<EnrollSys.Employee>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save"))
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].name)
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 20%" />
}
```

**Using an EditorTemplate**

In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Employee.cshtml`

```
@model EnrollSys.Employee
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name)
```

and in the main view

```
@model IEnumerable<EnrollSys.Employee> // can be IEnumerable
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save"))
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 20%" />
}
```