# Html.BeginForm not returning values to controller

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Why is this returning null to the controller?  The checkbox items are displaying but when I select items to save, the items in the controller action are null.

In the view

```
@model List<SearchOptionsViewModel>  
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save","Query", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <li id="li_15">
        <div>
            <p class="padding" />
             @foreach (var item in Model)
             {
                 <div>
                     @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.Selected)
                     @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Value)
                     @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Text)
                 </div>
             }
         </div>
     </li>
     <p>
         <input type="submit" value="Save" />
     </p>
}
```

Action

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Save(List<SearchOptionsViewModel> param)
{
    foreach (var item in param)
    {
      // Do stuff
    }
}
```

View Model

```
public class SearchOptionsViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your Action does not match what is there in Controller  @using (Html.BeginForm("Save","ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))

Comment: in form you have mentioned `actionname` as `Search` where in controller your `actionname` is `Save`.. How come??

Comment: That was a typo sorry about that.

Comment: Because you need to use a `for` loop or a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `SearchOptionsViewModel`, not a `foreach` loop. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363177/mvc-action-isnt-triggered-in-controller/30363319#30363319) for mote details

Comment: I'd suggest 2 things to help you troubleshoot this, you can do them independently or together.  (1) Use fiddler and look at the body of the Form Post to see what is being passed. (2) switch the argument for the (HttpPost) Save Action to FormCollection and investigate what is being sent to the server. -- My guess is that the name properties on the generated form controls are the problem

Comment: The REAL problem is likely that ASP.NET is not interpretting your form post correctly when translating the body of the request to type List<SearchOptionsViewModel> -- there is some magic happening under the hood and I think it's getting confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide a numeric indexer (from a `for` loop) to the HTML Helper. If you use `foreach` you don't get that. This is because you want the HTML Helpers to render in the form `foo[1].Value` so that the Model Parser can correctly convert the POSTed HTML form field values into your strongly-typed collection (which is your ViewModel):

```
@for( int i = 0; i < this.Model.Count; i++ )
{
    <div>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor( m => m[i].Selected)
    @Html.HiddenFor( m => m[i].Value)
    @Html.DisplayFor( m => m[i].Text)
    </div>
}
```