# MVC How to use IEnumerable variables stored in ViewBag in the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Below is the simplified code where the error occurs in View:

Model:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public string EmployeeID{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = selectAllEmployees();
        ViewBag.ITDept = model.Where(a => a.departmentID == 4);
        ViewBag.Officer = model.Where(a => a.departmentID == 5);
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@model IList<EnrolSys.Models.Employee>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "EmployMaster"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.ITDept.Count(); i++)
    {
        //Here's the error occurs
        @Html.Partial("EmployeeDisplayControl", ViewBag.ITDept[i])
    }
    <br />
}
```

In the line `@Html.Partial("EmployeeDisplayControl", ViewBag.ITDept[i])`, there's an exception:

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>'
>   has no applicable method named 'Partial' but appears to have an
>   extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically
>   dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the
>   extension method without the extension method syntax.

I guess it's saying I can't use extension methods in dynamic expression, is there any workaround for this??

I've Made a Fiddle for this error:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/ekDH06

Comment: have you tried using razor syntax 
@foreach(var i in Viewbag.ITDept)
{
@Html.Partial("EmployeeDisplayControl", @i)
}

Comment: @MartynWeber I can't use foreach as I have to do some Update in the partial View, I've tried using foreach loop before and it couldn't bind data to the model when post back, see this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363177/mvc-action-isnt-triggered-in-controller/30363319#30363319

Comment: Try `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.Partial(@Html, "EmployeeDisplayControl", ViewBag.ITDept[i]);`

Comment: Or simply `@Html.Partial("EmployeeDisplayControl", (object)ViewBag.ITDept[i])`

Comment: Your use of `@Html.Partial()` wont work in this case (btw you linked to my answer) because a partial will not generate the correct name attributes

Comment: You need to start with a view model containing 2 properties `List<Employee> ITDeptEmployees` and `List<Employee> OfficerEmployees`, then use a `for` loop on each collection (using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Name)` or using a custom `EditorTemplate`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your suggestion, I will give it a try tomorrow morning..

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh....It helps, your answer is correct...if you wish, please post it as an answer so I can accept..

Comment: @User2012384, Alex Art's answer is also correct so you should accept that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Editor/Display templates for this:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
   public IList<Employee> ITDept {get; set;}
   public IList<Employee> Officers {get; set;}
   //other properties here
}
```

Define an editor or display template for your Employee model (you should place it under Views/Shared/EditorTemplates or Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates accordingly):

The template could look like this (of course it is a simplified version):

```
@model EnrolSys.Models.Employee

<div>
   @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Name)
</div>
```

Now the view for Index action is going to receive a YourViewModel as a model
and you can simply use:

```
@model YourViewModel 


@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "EmployMaster"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.ITDept)
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you use

```
ViewBag.ITDept = model.Where(a => a.departmentID == 4);
```

you get an `IEnumerable` in `Viewbag.ITDept`, not an `IList`. That means you can't use an indexer (like `ViewBag.ITDept[i]`), as an IEnumerable doesn't support random access.

One solution:

```
ViewBag.ITDept = model.Where(a => a.departmentID == 4).ToList();
```

now it *is* a List, so you can use an indexer.

Other solution: do not use a "for" loop, but a "foreach":

```
foreach (var employee in ViewBag.ITDept)
{
    @Html.Partial("EmployeeDisplayControl", employee )
}
```

Maybe you still need to cast that ViewBag.ITDept to `IEnumerable<Employee>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a static type for the dynamic expression. Try this:

```
@Html.Partial("EmployeeDisplayControl", (object)ViewBag.ITDept[i])
```