# How can i bind a nested list to view with groupby() MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of model like this

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GroupID { get; set; }
}
```

In controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(ListGroup);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<Group> listModel) {
        @ViewBag.Success = "Update Suceess";
        return View(listModel);

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(Group ModelSearch) { 
        List<Group> listResult = ListGroup.Where(m=>m.GroupID == ModelSearch.GroupID).ToList();
        if (ModelSearch.GroupID == null) return View("Index", ListGroup);
        return View("Index", listResult);
    }
```

In view i group the list as below:

```
        @foreach (var items in Model.GroupBy(m => m.GroupID).Select(g => g.ToList()))
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">@items.ElementAt(0).GroupID</td>
            </tr>
            foreach (var item in items) 
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.GroupID)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Name)</td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
```

It can display as groups well but i cannot get value back to controller after button submit was fired. 
How can i bind model to view that controller can understand and receive data from view.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop - it generates elements with duplicate `name` attributes which cannot be bound to a collection (does not have the necessary indexers). It also creates invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes. You need to use a `for` loop of a custom `EditorTemplate` for the type.

Comment: can you explain more about EditorTemplate

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363177/mvc-action-isnt-triggered-in-controller/30363319#30363319) explains using both a `for` loop and a custom `EditorTemplate`

Comment: as you can see, i have two loops to display this list, how can i apply that. and there are lists inside a list

Comment: You can use nested loops but if your trying to post back to `public ActionResult Index(List<Group> listModel)` its not going to work anyway. You will need to create a view model to represent want  you want to display/edit in the view.

Answer (score 0):

according to my understanding,
you need to use a for loop rather than a foreach this will index your collections, by doing this modelbinder will work.

```
@for(var i = 0; i < items; i++)
{
             <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].GroupID)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Name)</td>
            </tr>

 }
```

Comment: the problem here is, there are many lists inside the list so i cannot apply this code.